# Android SQLite Columns ..... are not unique

Tags: java, android, sql

I am using SQLite on android and am getting this error

```
02-11 18:05:37.224: E/SQLiteDatabase(26583): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columns name, foreign_word are not unique (code 19)
```

However, this is called right after onUpgrade() is called, so there should be nothing in the database itself. This is the SQL Statement used :

```
private static final String CREATE_DB_TB_2 = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_WORD_ENGLISH
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_CORRECT
        + " BYTE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (" + COLUMN_NAME + ","
        + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + "))";
```

As there is nothing in the database as I drop the table, why am I getting the error when I add something?? Furthermore, I am calling context.deleteDatabase(NAME); every time I run the app. The thing must be unique as the table is empty !

Thanks in advance

Full LogCat:

```
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631): Error inserting correct=0 english_meaning= tener prisa foreign_word=to be in a hurry  name=AQA GCSE Spanish Higher
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: columns name, foreign_word are not unique (code 19)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1525)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1395)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at com.sharma.gcsevocabtester.DatabaseManipulator.addWord(DatabaseManipulator.java:168)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at com.sharma.gcsevocabtester.DatabaseManipulator$ImportVocabList.onPostExecute(DatabaseManipulator.java:420)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at com.sharma.gcsevocabtester.DatabaseManipulator$ImportVocabList.onPostExecute(DatabaseManipulator.java:1)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
02-11 18:38:02.811: E/SQLiteDatabase(28631):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Furthermore, I'm not sure if this will make a difference but I also have another table which is created using this String.

```
private static final String CREATE_DB_TB_1 = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_VOCAB_INFO + "(" + COLUMN_NAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_DOWNLOADED + " TEXT NOT NULL)";
```

ImportVocabList is an Asynctask. This is the onPostExecute :

```
**
     * Method called after execution has happen, passing in the result
     * 
     * @Override
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Word> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        boolean b = false;
        open();
        for (Word w : result) {

            addWord(w, vlName);
        }
        if (getAllVocabListsWhere(DatabaseManipulator.COLUMN_DOWNLOADED,
                "false").size() == 0) {
            b = true;
        }
        close();
        if (b) {
            context.finish();
        }
    }
```

The method addWord is as follows :

```
          public boolean addWord(Word w, String name) {
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN, w.getWordForeign());
        cv.put(COLUMN_WORD_ENGLISH, w.getWordEnglish());
        cv.put(COLUMN_CORRECT, w.getCorrect());
        database.insert(TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS, null, cv);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL ERROR");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem has been fixed - there were duplicate entries but they were ignored. Thanks

Comment: "why am I getting the error when I add something??" What are you trying to add? Is it a duplicate?

Comment: It can't be a duplicate if it is empty.

Comment: What are you adding: one row, multiple rows? (Post your `onUpgrade()` method.) If you are deleting the database why is `onUpgrade()` even being called? Logic stands that `onCreate()` should be called. Please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: Ok -  I added the database.delete after

Comment: I cannot help you unless you post the code where you are trying to insert the words into your table... Also your Logcat mentions nothing about `onUpgrade()`, the problem is between `ImportVocabList` and `addWord()`.  **Post this code.**

Comment: Have you verified that each Word object in `result` is unique? I have a strong feeling there is a duplicate value in there...

Comment: I working on that now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method, I am confident that your have at least one duplicate set of values in `result`.  Simply purge these duplicates from your source.

Or you can [tell your table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) to ignore the rows with duplicate entries and carry on via a ["conflict-clause"](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

```
private static final String CREATE_DB_TB_2 = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_WORD_ENGLISH
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_CORRECT
        + " BYTE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (" + COLUMN_NAME + ","
        + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + ") ON CONFLICT IGNORE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `foreign_word` make up your primary (Unique!) key in this table. you must be trying to insert duplicated keyed rows. The combination of the two fields must be unique.

Comment: sure...you don't have any other constraints applied to the table do you?

Comment: What do you mean by constraints? (I'm an SQL Noob) All I have on the table is that String in the op

Comment: any constraint on the table's data (Primary Key constrains that column(s) to be unique, you can constrain columns to contain only certain data (like `Yes` or `No`)

Comment: Nope. All I have defined is what I have is in that string

Comment: a Constraint error is data related. I suspect your CREATE_TABLE_xxx worked, and you are loading data (can you throw in a Log.d() in there?)

Comment: I'm not quite sure exactly what you want me to do. I think my create table worked as it is in a try catch block with SQLiteException. What do you want this Log.d() to record and where?

Comment: well, just wanted to make sure you are getting PAST the `create table ..` successfully. this error makes no sense for `create table ...` so you must be past that.

Comment: FYI you could google `SQLiteConstraintException code 19` and see lots of folks with the same data problem.

Comment: I did in fact, but most of the errors didnt specify which columns were the problem

Comment: that's the beauty of constraints...! errors will typically (but probably not always) tell you which constraint failed. makes it much easier to track down the (data) issue.

Comment: However, I'm still not sure what the entire issue is.

Comment: You created the table with one constraint...that being the Primary Key. Primary Keys are by definition unique. you must have tried to enter some rows with the same (unique) key...Boom!

Comment: But how if there is NOTHING in the table?

Comment: i would think there would be one (unique!) row in there. it should fail on the INSERT of one of the next few rows (where ever the duplicate is).

Comment: Look at the very first line of your logcat. It shows the insert statement that's causing it.

Comment: in `DatabaseManipulator.java` you have a function `addWord()` that seems to be an `INSERT`. i would suggest you log the values of `name` and `foreign_word` prior to doing the `INSERT`. that way you can look at the log and see what the duplicate values are that cause this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS, null, cv);
```

It worked for me for reasons I ignore.